# Паттерны проектирования на Си

Tags: c, проектирование, embedded, шаблоны-проектирования

Интересуют книги или большие статьи по паттернам проектирования для языка си. Хочется реализовать крупный проект встроенной системы на языке Си, но понимаю, что абы как написать код для неё не получится. Исходя из чего, хотелось бы изучить уже устоявшиеся и проверенные временем паттерны для написания крупных программ. Учитывая, что си - не объектно-ориентированный язык программирования, не совсем представляю, как в нем можно использовать паттерны из ООП.

Больше всего интересуют общие моменты по написанию модулей библиотек (заголовочного файла .h и файла реализации .с), а конкретно их структуру, взаимосвязи с другими библиотеками, структуру и рациональное разбиение (декомпозиция) всей программы на составляющие, связи этих частей, слои абстракции и тому подобное. А так же хотелось бы найти общие правила и требования для написания крупных программ на языке Си.

Буду очень благодарен за любую информацию!

Comment: Не увлекайтесь слишком сильно книжками про паттерны, лучше набивайте руку на практике. Не начинайте думать над хитрым архитектурным решением, пока у вас нет проблемы, которую оно бы решило.

Comment: Использовать конструкции ООП можно и на фортране и на ассемблере, а вот паттерны эти imho от того, что те кто не умеют программировать, учат, как программировать

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за совет!)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, просто, должны же элементарно быть какие-то правила в написании кода и библиотек, по которым другие программисты могут в нем интуитивно разобраться и по необходимости дополнять, и, с точки зрения масштабирумости, он выглядел бы приемлемо!?..

Comment: @PavelGridin, интересная мысль) но, я считал, что шаблоны проектирования, в первую очередь, это проверенные годами и безопасные "строительные материалы" для создания сложных систем..

Comment: @Maks, не, похоже на инфомошенничество, лучше изучать классику типа: Дональд Кнут: Искусство программирования.

Comment: *"проверенные годами и безопасные ..."* Оно может и так, но обычно к изучению паттернов подходят неправильно: заучивают их список и названия, а вместо этого нужно практиковаться и накапливать в разуме запас разных полезных приемов. Можно пролистать книгу по паттернам для расширения кругозора, чтобы посмотреть, какие приемы бывают, но молиться на них не нужно.

Comment: Главное, не начинать придумывать, как бы похитрее организовать код. Когда у вас появляется задача или проблема, вы находите для нее блестящее решение и реализуете его, а не сидите и не думаете, как сделать что-то умно.

Comment: Для примера можете посмотреть на [одну из реализаций libc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src)

Comment: Большой проект на Си - это как постройка дома на пустыре. Можно конечно разметить землю и сразу заказать мебель, но лучше всё-таки начинать с общего плана дома, а строить с фундамента. И главное, не смешивать подвал с чердаком - голова потом болеть будет.

Comment: Проблемы 95-98% (говно)кода современности в том, что все почему-то думают о **коде**, когда надо о **структурах данных**. Вот с этого и начните.